# Rails 3.1 server start fails with "Abort trap: 6"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to do a `rails s` on my Rails 3.1 App I am getting:

```
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0038 p:-17557387368028 s:0124 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 TOP   
c:0037 p:---- s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 CFUNC  :require
c:0036 p:0012 s:0118 b:0118 l:000102 d:000117 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240
c:0035 p:0005 s:0116 b:0116 l:000107 d:000115 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223
c:0034 p:0045 s:0114 b:0114 l:000113 d:000113 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640
c:0033 p:0041 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223
c:0032 p:0019 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240
c:0031 p:0150 s:0097 b:0097 l:000096 d:000096 TOP    /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:66
c:0030 p:---- s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 FINISH
c:0029 p:---- s:0093 b:0093 l:000092 d:000092 CFUNC  :require
c:0028 p:0012 s:0089 b:0089 l:000073 d:000088 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240
c:0027 p:0005 s:0087 b:0087 l:000078 d:000086 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223
c:0026 p:0045 s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640
c:0025 p:0041 s:0079 b:0079 l:000078 d:000078 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223
c:0024 p:0019 s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240
c:0023 p:0083 s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 TOP    /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin.rb:7
c:0022 p:---- s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 CFUNC  :require
c:0020 p:0026 s:0059 b:0059 l:000040 d:000058 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0019 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0091 s:0051 b:0051 l:000040 d:000050 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0016 p:---- s:0046 b:0046 l:000045 d:000045 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 CFUNC  :each
c:0014 p:0046 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0013 p:0021 s:0037 b:0037 l:000036 d:000036 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122
c:0012 p:0089 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 TOP    /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:7
c:0011 p:---- s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0016 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:52
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0721 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0000f8 d:000678 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0000f8 d:0000f8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: I've seen "Abort trap: 6" segmentation faults when passing options to Redcarpet, though I've not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are using the **thin** web server which relies on **EventMachine** for its network IO.

EventMachine contains **native code** which is compiled for your machine's architecture when the gem is installed. If the gems are moved between machines or the OS is updated or restored then you may need to recompile the native bits.

Since you are using an **rvm gemset** there is a simple command to recompile all gems in the current gemset:

```
rvm gemset pristine
```

Or across all gemsets:

```
rvm all-gemsets do rvm gemset pristine
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

fixed it for me. Maybe specify what you're using even if there's a default selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the problem. Comment out some code. Remove some gems. Eventually you'll pinpoint exactly which piece is failing.

If all else fails, report it as a ruby bug at http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem when updating my OS. Did you recently upgrade to Mountain Lion or the like? If you are on a mac, make sure you have the xCode command line tools installed.

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.