# Rails fails with zsh: abort or abort trap: 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, zsh

When I try to run something with a rails environment, I got an error.

```
bundle exec rake about
zsh: abort bundle exec rake about
```

I tried to switch to bash

```
bundle exec rake about
abort trap: 6
```

I tried to switch ruby version and reinstall all gems as suggested [Rails 3.1 server start fails with "Abort trap: 6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641803/rails-3-1-server-start-fails-with-abort-trap-6)

As I understand this could happen when C tries to write to memory which has no permissions.
[C: "zsh: abort" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937212/c-zsh-abort-error)

It happens only on my MacBook in one project. The rest of rails projects works well. And project works on another MacBook as well!

Ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin18]

Rails 5.2.2

MacOS Catalina 10.15.3

[Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/anaumov/3ee57674a1d204cb6cf466fb9c786ca0)

Comment: Was this working and the stopped? Try clearing out bundler's directory for the project and `bundle install` again.

Comment: @jordanm I tried this. I completely removed ruby version from rbenv with gems and reinstall everything. It does not work. Also, it never worked. Will try to add logs to bundle and see at what step in breaks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on my Catalina 10.15.7 (although it were happening on all projects) and managed to make the rails / rake commands work following this gist - https://gist.github.com/ritaly/9ded38e1918e55b928ff357fbdf07417

Basically the system could not find some openssl libraries, so we create a link for them to the `/usr/local/lib/` folder.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```

The tricky thing was that there was no error output, not even in the Mac console.

**Replace `openssl@1.1/1.1.1d` with your Openssl version/revision.**